# Interrupt cin while loop without the user entering input

Tags: c++, linux, while-loop, interrupt, cin

In `main`, I give the user the ability to enter a command to stop the application:

```
while( run_processes && cin >> command_line_input ){
```

I'd also like to stop the application elsewhere by setting `run_processes = false;`.

However, when I set `run_processes` to `false`, the above loop doesn't stop without the user entering input.

How can I properly interrupt the loop without the user entering input?

Comment: show more code : where and how exactly do you set it to false ?

Comment: @quantdev In another boost thread.  I apologize for leaving out a key detail, that I'd like the loop to stop without user input.  I've confirmed that `run_processes` is properly being set.  Does `cin` not necessarily depend upon user input for the `while` to proceed?  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If you create another thread which calls `cin >> command_line_input` (and then send the string to the main thread), then you can decide in the main thread not to wait for thread reading from `cin`. I don't think it's possible to abort the `cin >> command_line_input` call itself in a portable way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to interrupt `std::cin` in a portable way.

You could however resolve to non-portable solution, e.g. manually `poll()` the standard input on a UNIX system and check `run_processes` while polling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the following solution is standard enough, but it works on both my Fedora Linux (GCC 10.3) & Windows 10 (MSVC 16.11)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, [] (int s)
    {
        std::signal(s, SIG_DFL);
        std::fclose(stdin);
        std::cin.setstate(std::ios::badbit); // To differentiate from EOF input
    });

    std::string input;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input));

    std::cout << (std::cin.bad() ? "interrupted" : "eof") << std::endl;
}
```

Don't ask me how to reuse `cin` from that state now.

Answer (score 0):

> Does cin not necessarily depend upon user input for the while to
>   proceed?

Yes, the user would have to enter input each loop.

```
bool stop = false;
std::string command;
int count = 0;
while(stop==false && std::cin>>command)
{
    ++count;
    std::cout<<count<<std::endl;
}
```

The code above only counts +1 after I enter something.
Unless you are changing the value of run_process based on the user input I don't see why it shouldn't work...?