# Can we apply a time constraint on time taken by user to enter input?

Tags: c++

i want to make a program that pint's number from 1-100 continuously until any input is given, so i thought if only there was a time limit in which user can give input. 
Like if the user fails to enter an input in that time then programs skips to next step, it will make it look mare natural rather than asking for input in each step.

Comment: This is what threading is for.  Once thread displays while the other waits for user input.

Comment: [Interrupt `std::cin`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24976180/1460794)

Comment: [Stop `std::cin` from another thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42395777/1460794)

Comment: How do you plan on accepting the user input?

Comment: using cin, because i only want an char, and if the input is true he program stops

Comment: `std::cin` will not work well for this. Rather use the [operating system's input functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441480/1460794).